# Why we use t-distribution when sample size is small? $(n < 30)$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

When population is normal, distribution of sample mean is also normal regardless of sample size $n$. Then, why we use t-distribution instead of normal distribution when sample size is small? $(n < 30)$

Comment: But you have an unknown standard deviation I'm guessing. When this is the case and you replace the standard deviation with the sample standard deviation, you end up with a $t$-distribution. (Remember if $X_i$ are iid $N\left(\mu,\sigma^2\right)$, $\overline{X}_n =\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits _{i =1}^{n}X_i$ and $S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i- \overline{X}_n\right)^2}$, then $\frac{\overline{X}_n - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}}\sim t_{n-1}$.)

Comment: When population variance $\sigma^2$ is unknown and estimated by sample variance $S^2,$ you should **always** use a t test for most accurate results. For $n > 30$ results from an incorrect z test may be a serviceable approximation. The approx 'rule of 30' works **only for 95% CIs or 5% significance levels** because 1.96 cuts 2.5% from upper tail of std normal and for $n > 30$ numbers around 2.0 cut 2.5% from upper tail of Student's t dist'n with $n - 1 \ge 30$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992333